# Keyboard random keys not working anymore (T, Y, F3, F7, Backspace)

Tags: drivers, keyboard, input-device

Switch Hitter result:

[image: Switch Hitter]

As you can see some keys are not working anymore.

What I did:

- Deleted keyboard drivers and restarted
- Unplugged / plugged keyboard
- Tried on another PC (exactly same issue on other PC)
- Tried another keyboard (other keyboard works perfectly)

Keyboard is a Gigabyte Aivia Osmium. Before throwing it away, I just want to be sure the problem is mechanical.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Keys on the keyboards are usually connected up in [matrix fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit).

If a number of them suddenly doesn't work anymore, all at once, this usually indicates that one of the row or column electrical connections of this matrix has failed. Because if such a line is broken, key presses cannot be detected anymore.

This may be caused by a mechanical problem (internal bending caused the electrical connection to break, for example).

The only way to find out for sure is to open it up, follow the traces, reconstruct the matrix, and see if the failed keys match one row or column.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open up the "broken" button, use the air spray to clean inside. You must be patient to clean them up. It may take 30 minutes for me to remove all the dirt inside.

Comment: p.s: sometimes you do not need to open all the "'broken" button